# How to start default browser with a URL(with spaces and #) for a local file? Delphi

Tags: html, delphi, browser

I want to open a local HTML file in the default browser.

For example: 
Default Browser is Mozilla Firefox.

The file to be opened: C:\My Custom Path\New Folder\AFile.htm

Please note the path has spaces. Depending on conditions I want to append an Id at the end of the URL.

Final URL is C:\My Custom Path\New Folder\AFile.htm#12345

If I open the browser manually, and paste the URL "C:\My Custom Path\New Folder\AFile.htm#12345".

It works fine. Unable to find the best way to do this through code.

Comment: Use `ShellExecuteEx` from the `ShellApi` unit

Comment: Case with the copying to browser is good in this situation. I wrote one more case. But copying looks better.

Comment: @Ari0nhh, `ShellExecuteEx` won't work with the anchor (#).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ShellExecute/Ex()` won't work directly using `"open"` verb with the anchor (`#`) in the URL. even if you use `file://` protocol the anchor will be omitted.

The best way is to get the path for the default browser, you can use [`FindExecutable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776419(v=vs.85).aspx), and then execute it and pass the URL as a parameter.

```
uses
  ShellAPI;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Res: HINST;
  Buffer: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
  SEInfo: TShellExecuteInfo;
  HtmlFile, Anchor: string;
begin
  HtmlFile := 'd:\1 - Copy.html';
  Anchor := '#123';

  FillChar(Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), 0);
  Res := FindExecutable(PChar(HtmlFile), nil, Buffer);
  if Res <= 32 then
    raise Exception.Create(SysErrorMessage(Res));

  FillChar(SEInfo, SizeOf(SEInfo), 0);
  SEInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(SEInfo);
  with SEInfo do
  begin        
    lpFile := PChar(string(Buffer));
    lpParameters := PChar(Format('"file:///%s"', [HtmlFile + Anchor]));
    nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;
    fMask := SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI; // Do not display an error message box if an error occurs.
  end;
  if not ShellExecuteEx(@SEInfo) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
end;
```

---

EDIT: Looks like the `file:///` URI scheme is important in cases where the URL includes query string parameters (e.g `file.html?param=foo#bar`) or else the `?` is escaped to `%3F` (tested in Chrome)

Comment: Do you know if this works with Microsoft Edge? Edge seems to have problem with URLs with '#'

Comment: I dont have Edge to test sorry. What kind of problem? Can you use the url in the browser directly?

Comment: This does not work with Microsoft Edge (anymore). The anchor will be stripped from the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't do it only with ShellExecute.
But there is some hack.

For example you want to open url like this:

**C:\Users\User\Desktop\Some sitename with spaces.htm** with the anchor **#myAnchor**

To make ShellExecute open file:

```
vS := 'file:///C:\Users\User\Desktop\Some sitename with spaces.htm#MyAnchor';
ShellExecute(0, 'OPEN', PChar(vS), '', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

It's Important to use **"file:///"** in the beginning, but *ShellExecute open this page without anchor*.

To open with the anchor you can dynamically create html file with content like this:

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv=Refresh content="0; url=file:///C:\Users\User\Desktop\Some sitename with spaces.htm#MyAnchor">
<body></body>
</html>
```

And open this dynamic file with ShellExecute.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

One can also create a process launching CMD.EXE with the following parameters :

```
'/C start '+Url
```

Quick and dirty, but it should work OK

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this. I get the default browser, and used the CreateProcess API to launch the browser with my custom URL.
Notice, I add the 'file:///' in the beginning and also surround the string with double quotes.

```
function GetDefaultBrowser(): String;
var
    ExecName: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
    FHandle: THandle;
    MyPath: String;
begin
    Result := '';
    MyPath := small.GetTempPath;
    FHandle := System.SysUtils.FileCreate(MyPath + 'AFile.htm');

    if FHandle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
    begin
        FillChar(ExecName, Length(ExecName), #0);
        if FindExecutable('AFile.htm', PChar(MyPath), ExecName) > 32 then
            Result := ExecName;
        System.SysUtils.FileClose(FHandle);
        System.SysUtils.DeleteFile(MyPath + 'AFile.htm');
    end;
end;


procedure LaunchHTMLPage(NumberToAppend : string);
var
    Start: TStartupInfo;
    Process: TProcessInformation;
    FileNameString, AppPathAndName, AppPathOnly: string;
begin
    AppPathAndName := GetDefaultBrowser ;

    //Break the AppPathAndName and get the path name to use later

    //I am adding double quotes in the path name to escape the spaces and the '#'
    FileNameString := AnsiQuotedStr('file:///' + Application.HelpFile + '#' + NumberToAppend, '"');
    AppPathAndName := AppPathAndName + ' ' + FileNameString;
    FillChar(Start, SizeOf(StartUpInfo), #0);
    FillChar(Process, SizeOf(TProcessInformation), #0);

    CreateProcess(nil, PChar(AppPathAndName), nil, nil, false, CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP + NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil, PChar(AppPathOnly), StartUpInfo, ProcessInfo);

end;
```

Comment: @kobik, I would accept an answer in a couple of days, I am waiting for more comments to find any mistakes/fail-cases if there are any.
It is possible that someone may have a better solution that what you provided.
On an unrelated note, my solution is not entirely based on your answer. You used ShellExecute, and I am using CreateProcess.

Comment: I don't think this will compile as "small" is not a declared identifier ?

Answer (score 0):

i think this is better way:

```
function OpenHtmlFile(FileAdr :string):Boolean;
var
  vTempFile :string;
  vData     :TStrings;
begin
  Result:= False;
  vTempFile:= GetTempFolder + '_tmphtmlrunfile.html';
  vData:= TStringList.Create;
  vData.Text:= '<html><head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=''file:///' + FileAdr + '''">';
  try
    try
      vData.SaveToFile(vTempFile, TEncoding.UTF8);
    finally
      vData.Free;
    end;
    ShellExecute(Handle,
             'open',
             PChar(vTempFile),
             nil,
             nil,
             SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    Result:= True;
  except
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation that supports all common web browsers and Microsoft Edge (Windows Store App).
It refers to the issues with queries (`?`) and fragments (`#`) in the URI and the issue with `file:///` protocol in combination with the Edge browser.
(I use it for HTML output of "Flare" software, that's why the "help" in the naming of variables)

```
// AHelpFileName := 'C:\temp\Default.htm';
// AHelpID := '123';

procedure TSomeClass.OpenHelp(const AHelpFileName, AHelpID: string);
var
  URL: string;
  BrowserPath, FileName, Parameters: PWideChar;
begin
  URL := Format('file:///%s', [AHelpFileName]);
  if AHelpID <> '' then
    URL := Format('%s#cshid=%s', [URL, AHelpID])

  URL := StringReplace(URL, '\', '/', [rfReplaceAll]);
  URL := StringReplace(URL, ' ', '%20', [rfReplaceAll]);

  BrowserPath := StrAlloc(MAX_PATH);
  Parameters := nil;

  if FindExecutable(PWideChar(AHelpFileName), nil, BrowserPath) > 32 then
  begin
    Parameters := PWideChar(URL);

    if SameText(ExtractFileName(BrowserPath), 'LaunchWinApp.exe') then
      // Default browser is a Windows Store App (and most likely it is Edge)
      FileName := 'shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge'
    else
      // IE, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Vivaldi, ...
      FileName := BrowserPath;
  end
  else
    FileName := PWideChar(URL);

  ShellExecute(0, nil, FileName, Parameters, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
end;
```