# Using ShellExecute, how do I display linked HTML files in the default browser

Tags: delphi, shellexecute

I've figured out the use of a parameter in the URL:

> For a topic, in Help&Manual, select the bottom tab named "Topic Options" and enter a topic name in the "Topic ID:" field.

My chosen topic id for the Login chapter is "login" and if I then use the URL:

`file:///D:/RiskModeller/Manual/HTML/index.html?login.htm`

the browser will open the manual at the login chapter.

I then tried the following code in Delphi:

```
procedure TfrmHelp.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Res: HINST;
  Buffer: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
  SEInfo: TShellExecuteInfo;
  HtmlFile, Anchor: string;
begin
  HtmlFile := 'D:\RiskModeller\Manual\HTML\index.html';
  Anchor := '?login.htm';

  FillChar(Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), 0);
  Res := FindExecutable(PChar(HtmlFile), nil, Buffer);
  if Res <= 32 then
    raise Exception.Create(SysErrorMessage(Res));

  FillChar(SEInfo, SizeOf(SEInfo), 0);
  SEInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(SEInfo);
  with SEInfo do
  begin
    lpFile := PChar(string(Buffer));
//    lpParameters := PChar(Format('"%s"', [HtmlFile + Anchor]));  {Nols ... Also not working}
    lpParameters := PChar(HtmlFile + Anchor);

    nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;
    fMask := SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI; // Do not display an error message box if an error occurs.
  end;
  if not ShellExecuteEx(@SEInfo) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
end;
```

But this Delphi code generates the following URL:

`file:///D:/RiskModeller/Manual/HTML/index.html%3Flogin.htm`

It should be:

`file:///D:/RiskModeller/Manual/HTML/index.html?login.htm`

Comment: Not sure how this HTML help works (it's been a while since I worked with Help&Manual), but in `index.htm?summary.htm`, the part after the question mark are parameters ('query string') to the url, and this can't be the actual filename. This value would only work if there is a script running in `index.htm` that takes this information.

Comment: The duplicate question is not for Delphi, but uses the same API calls you have available in Delphi. First `FindExecutable` to find the executable for opening an HTML file, and then `ShellExecute` to start that executable (the default browser), with the full url as a parameter.

Comment: Another near-duplicate, actually with Delphi code: [about url with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41044509/how-to-start-default-browser-with-a-urlwith-spaces-and-for-a-local-file-del), offering basically the same solution.

Comment: You need to include `file:///` URI scheme prefix. i.e. `lpParameters := PChar(Format('"file:///%s"', [HtmlFile + Anchor]));` I have updated my answer where you took your code from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41057749/937125

Comment: If this solves your issue I will mark this question a duplicate.

Comment: My problem is solved by using: PChar(Format('"file:///%s"', [HtmlFile + Anchor]));